# AJAX form redirecting to empty page instead of logging data

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return a JSON string to my javascript to display it, but instead it redirects the page to a page with the JSON values in it. I'm using this in a partial view.

**HTML** (partial view)

```
@model ProjectName.Model.EmployeeSearchModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EmployeeSearch", "Base", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "fnAjaxSuccess", OnFailure = "fnAjaxFailure" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Social, new { @class="form-control" })<br />

        <input type="submit" id="_empSearchSubmitBtn" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
}
```

**JS**

```
function fnAjaxSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data)
}
function fnAjaxFailure(error) {
    alert("An error occured: " + error);
    console.log(error);
}
```

**Controller Method** (this is in a different controller from the view I'm using it in)

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EmployeeSearch(EmployeeSearchModel model)
{
    return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I click on the submit button it redirects me to a page with:

```
"true"
```

I expect it to be just console.log() on the view I'm in.

Comment: Have you included the necessary Ajax Unobtrusive scripts?

Comment: I haven't, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use ajax beginform you need jquery and jquery-unobtrusive-ajax library. You can install it using nuget, search for "jQuery unobtrusive ajax" and then install it. After installing the library add jquery and jquery-unobtrusive-ajax to your layout page.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```